# Difference between let* and set? in Common Lisp

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I am working on a genetic programming hobby project.

I have a function/macro setup that, when evaluated in a setq/setf form, will generate a list that will look something like this.

```
(setq trees (make-trees 2)) 
==> (+ x (abs x))
```

Then it will get bound out to a lambda function `#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (X) ... >` via strategic use of functions/macros

However, I want to get a bit more effective with this than manually assigning to variables, so I wrote something like this:

```
(setq sample 
      (let* ((trees (make-trees 2))
         (tree-bindings (bind-trees trees))
         (evaluated-trees (eval-fitness tree-bindings))))
      (list (trees tree-bindings evaluated-trees)))
```

However, I get `EVAL: trees has no value` when I place this in a let form. My suspicion is that the macro expansions don't get fully performed in a LET as compared to a SETF, but that doesn't make sense to me.

What is the cause of this issue?

--- edit: yanked my code and put the whole file in a pastebin ---

Supposing that I decide that a setq isn't going to do it for me and I write a simple function to do it:

(defun generate-sample () 
      (let ((twiggs (make-trees 2)))
    (let ((tree-bindings (bind-trees twiggs)))
      (let ((evaluated-trees (eval-fitness tree-bindings)))
        (list twiggs tree-bindings evaluated-trees)))))

This yields an explosion of ...help file error messages (??!?)... and "eval: variable twiggs has no value", which stems from the bind-trees definition on SLIME inspection.

I am reasonably sure that I've completely hosed my macros. http://pastebin.org/673619

Comment: I don't understand exactly what your macro is doing.  And what is your "strategic use of functions/macros" doing, and what's with all the toplevel `setq`s?

Comment: Well, one setq is sort of the global 'pool of population'; the others are just artifacts of development. My macros generate dynamically a function from fairly arbitrary expression trees (it gets "sorta" complex to think about).

Comment: Your second snippet is incomplete.  What happens in the body of your `let` form?  The indentation is also misleading, and the parentheses are not balanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(Setq make-trees 2)` sets the value of the variable `make-trees` to 2, then returns 2.

I do not see a reason for a macro in what you describe.  Is it true that your `make-trees` creates a single random tree, which can be interpreted as a program?  Just define this as a function with `defun`.  I am thinking of something like this:

```
(defun make-tree (node-number)
  (if (= node-number 1)
      (make-leaf)
      (cons (get-random-operator)
            (mapcar #'make-tree
                    (random-partition (- node-number 1))))))
```

`Let` and `setq` do totally different things.  `Setq` assigns a value to an existing variable, while `let` creates a new lexical scope with a number of lexical bindings.

I think that you should present more of your code; currently, your question does not make a lot of sense.

---

*Update:*

I will fix your snippet's indentation to make things clearer:

```
(setq sample 
      (let* ((trees (make-trees 2))
             (tree-bindings (bind-trees trees))
             (evaluated-trees (eval-fitness tree-bindings))))
      (list (trees tree-bindings evaluated-trees)))
```

Now, as written before, `let*` establishes lexical bindings.  These
are only in scope within its body:

```
(setq sample 
      (let* ((trees (make-trees 2))
             (tree-bindings (bind-trees trees))
             (evaluated-trees (eval-fitness tree-bindings)))
        ;; here trees, tree-bindings, and evaluated-trees are bound
        ) ; end of let* body
      ;; here trees, tree-bindings, and evaluated trees are not in scope anymore
      (list (trees tree-bindings evaluated-trees)))
```

That last line is spurious, too.  If those names were bound, it would
return a list of one element, which would be the result of evaluating
the function `trees` with `tree-bindings` and `evaluated-trees` as
arguments.

You might get what you want like this:

```
(setq sample 
      (let* ((trees (make-trees 2))
             (tree-bindings (bind-trees trees))
             (evaluated-trees (eval-fitness tree-bindings)))
        (list trees tree-bindings evaluated-trees)))
```

---

*Another update:*

The purpose of macros is to eliminate repeated code when that elimination is not possible with functions.  One frequent application is when dealing with places, and you also need them to define new control constructs.  As long as you do not see that something cannot work as a function, do not use a macro for it.

Here is some code that might help you:

```
(defun make-tree-lambda (depth)
  (list 'lambda '(x)
        (new-tree depth)))

(defun make-tree-function (lambda-tree)
  (eval lambda-tree))

(defun eval-fitness (lambda-form-list input-output-list)
  "Determines how well the lambda forms approach the wanted function
by comparing their output with the wanted output in the supplied test
cases.  Returns a list of mean quadratic error sums."
  (mapcar (lambda (lambda-form)
            (let* ((actual-results (mapcar (make-tree-function lambda-form)
                                           (mapcar #'first input-output-list)))
                   (differences (mapcar #'-
                                        actual-results
                                        (mapcar #'second input-output-list)))
                   (squared-differences (mapcar #'square
                                                differences)))
              (/ (reduce #'+ squared-differences)
                 (length squared-differences))))
          lambda-form-list))

(defun tree-fitness (tree-list input-output-list)
  "Creates a list of lists, each inner list is (tree fitness). Input
is a list of trees, and a list of test cases."
  (mapcar (lambda (tree fitness)
            (list tree fitness))
          tree-list
          (eval-fitness (mapcar #'make-tree-lambda tree-list)
                        input-output-list)))
```

Comment: @Svante - at work now, can't get the code - but when I do put it in like that, I get "trees not a value".

Comment: @Paul Nathan:  Well, if I mock up what you showed, it does not.  Have you tried stepping it?

Comment: @Svante: I am flumoxxed beyond my understanding. My file's up in a pastebin link. >.<

Comment: @Paul Nathan:  I have added some comments to your pastebin.  The central issue seems to be that you do not understand what macros are there for.  Especially your `bind-trees`, but also the `eval-fitness` are quite inscrutable for me.

Comment: @Svante: thank you for your comments on my lisp. I am still learning. What I am *trying* to do is randomly construct a list (a 'tree') using the operator lists and an arbitrary value X, then take that 'tree' and construct an anonymous function out of it. Given that randomly generated function, I want to run it with some sample values(`eval-fitness`) and see if it fits the goal-function. My next goal is to swap branches of the tree to try to improve the goal function. I am using macros to essentially "paste in" the tree to a template (lambda (X) tree).

Comment: -improve the goal function,+improve the randomly generated function